# Skew and shadow delta

Tags: options, volatility, delta, volatility-skew, forward-start

> The presence of skew causes a correlation between volatility and spot. This correlation produces a negative shadow delta for all forward starting products (forward starting options have a theoretical delta of zero).

How does this produce a negative shadow delta? The exact mechanism is not clear to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, the author is saying that the delta of an option,

$dC/dS = \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial S}$,

where the $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$ is the delta assuming constant volatility,  the $\frac{\partial C}{\partial v}$ is the vega of the option, and the $\frac{\partial v}{\partial S}$ describes how the implied volatility of the option moves as the spot price moves.  This second term is the "shadow delta" being referred to.

Comment: The use of a total derivative was what I was missing here